# Octave: Dynamic file name for printing plots to eps

Tags: matlab, octave

In a for-loop, I generate several plots. Depending on the counter in my for-loop, I want to save the plot to a different file name.

What I've tried is a follows, but the problem is, is that the file is literally saved as "figures{i}.eps"... How can I ensure that *print* evaluates *figures{i}*? I've tried *eval()*, but that resulted in the plot being saved as "eval(figures{i}.eps"

```
figures={'training.eps', 'testing.eps', ... }

for i=1:ntrials 
   % generate plot etc.

   print -deps -color figures{i};
endfor
```

Any help would be appreciated..

Comment: [`sprintf`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sprintf.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider using the function syntax instead of the command syntax for your print function:

```
print("-deps","-color",figures{i})
```

Octave command syntax passes the arguments as strings

See https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/v4.0.1/Commands.html#Commands

Also a more concise way to write it:

```
print(figures{i},"-depsc")
```